# Can someone explain this php function to me?

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand everything this PHP function does. A game has this code and I'm trying to determine how much XP it takes to level for each level.

```
function xpToNextLevel($level){

    if($level == 0){
        return 200;
    }

    $s = 500;
    $m = 0xFFFF * ($level / 98);
    $xp = floor((($m - $s) * ($level / 98)) + $s);

    return $xp;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: like it says `$xp = floor((($m - $s) * ($level / 98)) + $s);`

Comment: Can you narrow it down? Which part(s) of it don't you understand?

Comment: Wow. That was a quick down vote.
@TomFenech If I set $level = 4, where does it go? And although I've found many answers regarding 0xFFFF on StackOverflow, I don't see how that fits with this.

Comment: 0xFFFF stands for the number 65535

Comment: @Gab Thank you. Rather than downvoting, I appreciate that you at least provided some information and edited the question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's great to look over other people's code (open-source or with permission that is) to better understand the language. While I understand the down-voting, as google would have been a good resource to figure this out, I'll try to explain it the best I can.

To help explain it, I have rewritten a bit of your code for you.

```
function xpToNextLevel($level){

        if($level == 0){
            return 200;
        }

        $d = $level / 98;
        $s = 500;
        $m = 65535 * $d; /* 65535 is equivalent to 0xFFFF */
        $k = $m - $s; /* takes (0xFFFF * ($level / 98)) - $s */
        $dk = $k * $d; /* takes ($m - $s) * ($level/98) */
        $unroundedXP = $dk + $s; /* adds (($m-$s) * ($level/98)) to $s */
        $xp = floor($unroundedXP); /* rounds the experience down. */

        return $xp;
}
```

so, I know in your comment you asked about the level 4. Let's trace through that!

```
4 != 0 // thus we continue.
4/98 = 2/49 /*which is roughly ~0.04082, but for the sake of accuracy, I'll leave it as 2/49 */
65535 * (2/49) = ~2674.89795
2674.89795 - 500 = 2174.89795
2174.89795 * 2/49 = ~88.771345
88.771344 + 500 = 588.771344 //This is the unrounded experience
Experience = 588
```

The floor function basically rounds to the lowest integer. In positive numbers, this means we take the number and toss out everything behind the decimal point. So the number returned is roughly 588. I say roughly because a computer would be more exact about it.

By the way, I believe this is most comparable to a "Arithmetic Series." More information about that can be found here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html

Comment: Fantastic answer and well detailed! I realize that the question was rather simple. I appreciate that you took the time to explain this. Thank you.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

So, let's simplify the formula mathematically. Following formulas are *not* a PHP code, but pure mathematics!

```
xp = ((65535 * (level / 98)) - 500) * (level / 98) + 500
```

... which simplifies to ...

```
xp = (65535 / 98^2) * level^2 - (500 / 98) * level + 500
```

... which is *approximately* equivalent to ...

```
xp = 6.8 * level^2 - 5.1 * level + 500
```

As You can [see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y=6.8%2ax%5E2-5.1%2ax%2b500), the amount of experience needed for next level grows quadratically along the formula above.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning explicitly that this is invalid PHP syntax. To raise a number to a power you need to do `pow($level, 2)` or `$level*$level`. Also, your second and third line are not equal.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, the formulas are meant *mathematically*, but I'll better mention it in the answer. And You are correct, the third formula is just to give an insight.

Comment: Brilliant! Perfect answer I was looking for.